# C Program to find maximum and minimum between two numbers using functions

Tags: c, function, recursion, max, min

I was solving a code of maximum and minimum using functions. I wrote the code like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int maxmin(int x, int y);

int main () {
    int a, b, c;

    scanf("%d%d", &a, &b);

    c = maxmin(a, b);

    if (maxmin == 1) {
        printf("%d is maximum,%d is minimum", a, b);
    }
    else
        printf("%d is maximum,%d is minimum", b, a);

    return 0;    
}

int maxmin(int x, int y) {
    int XisMax = 0;
    if (x > y) {
        XisMax=1;
    }
    else {
        XisMax=0;
    }
    return XisMax;
}
```

So my output shows this results:

```
Input:9,10;
10 is maximum,9 is minimum

Input:10,9;
9 is maximum,10 is minimum
```

What is the mistake here? What should I do?

PS:I have an exam on functions so solutions using functions will be helpful.

Comment: Typo? `if (maxmin==1)` should be `if (c==1)`.

Comment: You have a function named maxmin, you need to change the if condition to if ( maxmin(a,b) == 1 )

Comment: @SPlatten OP already called the function and is using intermediate variables and this is legitimate, as in the function too.

Comment: @SPlatten you mean like this? if (maxmin(a,b)==1)
    {
        printf("%d is maximum,%d is minimum",a,b);
    }
    else
        printf("%d is maximum,%d is minimum",b,a);
    return 0;

Comment: @Yunnosch OP already called the function with `c= maxmin(a,b);` and does not need to call it again as suggested. The suggestion might be better practice, but is not the actual error. There is no harm in using intermediate variables, as OP's code does both in `main()` and in `maxmin()`, and the compiler will probably optimise them out.

Comment: @MustabirApurbo, yes, you can get rid of the first call and just use it in the if, also if you cut and paste (move) the minmax function to above main then you don't need the prototype.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if (maxmin==1)

change to`if (c==1)`

your problem is solve.
Have a Good day

Answer (score 0):

You should be checking if(c == 1), not if(maxmin == 1).

Your function can also be made shorter:

```
int maxmin(int x, int y)
{
    if (x>y)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
       return 0;
    }
}
```

Also, I *think* your scanf is missing a comma between the two %d's.